# What can a negative offset means in "load word" instruction in MIPS decompiled code

Tags: reverse-engineering, mips, disassembly

I am reverse engineering a C MIPS application, in some places I can see negative offsets in *lw* opcode, like:

```
80032910                 lw      $v0, -4($s4)
```

Positive offsets usually indicate some kind of structure, where one of the members is being accessed, but what code can lead to a negative offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, it can be generated if you read the previous value of a pointer, e.g. traversing an array from the end to the beginning

```
int *myDataEnd;

... code ...

while(*myDataEnd > *(myDataEnd-1))
  myDataEnd--;
```

Referencing the integer pointed by `myDataEnd-1` may generate that instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Position independent code uses $gp as a pointer into the middle of a 64K region of global data, so you will often see `lw $t0, -nnn($gp)` in code.  If the depth of a stack frame is unpredictable at compile-time, a frame pointer may be used to mark the start of the stack frame, causing there to be memory references with negative offsets to the frame pointer.

Hand optimized code can also use negative offsets to save reloading an address into a register.